# GUDID / Device Registration Common Data Element

Tags: openfda, database

Is there a field or data element common to both the UID and the device registration databases in FDA?  I'm trying to tie the two together but can't seem to find a common field.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the UDI and Device Registration endpoints do not have a common field that could unambiguously identify a device between the two.

Comment: Thank you.  I have found that the "proprietary name" in FDA and either "brand name" or "device description" do match up somewhat, but like you said, it's not necessarily unambiguous.